# Why is Import[file, "CSV"] faster than Import[file, "TSV"]

Tags: import, csv-format, tsv-format

I have a lot of data which use tabs as field separators. There are no tab characters in their fields. The data are all alphanumerical, strings are not enclosed in quotes.

Theoretically `Import[file, "TSV"]` should be quicker than `Import[file, "CSV"]`, because a CSV file can contain escaped commas within fields. There is no such feature for TSV files. That's why they should theoretically be read more quickly.

However, I tested

`AbsoluteTiming[Import["myFile.tsv", "CSV"]][[1]]`

and

`AbsoluteTiming[Import["myFile.tsv", "TSV"]][[1]]`

Comparing these figures, I see that the CSV version is about 40% faster than the TSV version for my 40MB test file.

Of course, I killed the kernel between tests because there seems to be some sort of buffering: When I repeat the commands, the repeated commands go about 10% faster.

**Why is the CSV version quicker?**

**Is it more reliable in my situation, to import the file with the CSV version or with the TSV version?**

My test was with Mathematica 12.3.0.0 under Linux x86 (64-bit).